# Getting GPU statistics from /proc (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, proc

I am trying to get load statistics from my GPUs (NVIDIA). Is there a place in the /proc file system where I could find something useful, akin to /proc/stat to get CPU info?

I know there are command line tools to do this, but in my particular case these will not do as I will run the monitor in a container. I can mount /proc from the host to my monitoring container and access anything that is in there, but I cannot run commands on the host.

How would I do this, or is this something that cannot be done?

Comment: tried 'nvidia-smi'?

Comment: Does not work from a docker container. This is why I need to find something in /proc I can read.

Comment: Of course could be another file system location as well but thought /proc might be the most promising place to look.

Comment: I didn't even know you could talk directly to a GPU from Docker, you learn something new every day!

Comment: I do not know if you can, nor do I care.  I am only running my monitoring script in a container for reasons not relevant to this. The script is about 100 lines of very standard Python.  My question is, can I get this info from the /proc file system or not.